# Parse column using BCP file format or similar

Tags: sql-server, bcp, sql-server-bcp

I was using BCP file format for bulk insert and it was working well. I could parse files into columns I needed.
Now I have content of file in a table. Each row of file is one row in table.
Is there any way I can create a view which would parse column by the specified format?

Basically, I need same functionality as BULK INSERT has with FORMATFILE, except I need to use table instead of file.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: So you have a table with a single column of string data? Now you need to split it out into columns?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I have table with one column LINE VARCHAR(4000). I need to parse it according to format I should store somewhere. Table will have only one format at the time (when imported from the file all lines would have the same format) but it can be different formats that will be imported to the same table.

Comment: So you just need a way to specify the delimiter and split the string. I would highly recommend you read this http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings. It talks you through various ways of creating a function to split strings based on a delimiter.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at the article. I think problem might be different format types. Some have 5 columns, some have 50 columns. Also some user ; or , as separtator while some are length based.